# ¿Como encontrar el numero que le sigue al mayor de 30 de ellos, ingresado por consola?

Tags: java, bucle-for

Tengo que ingresar 30 números e imprimir el numero mayor y el que le sigue.
Tengo problemas en como buscar el numero que le sigue al mayor,  por el momento hice esto (aunque no es de la manera correcta como la pide en la consigna, ya que el numero siguiente debe estar dentro de los números que ingreso, y no sumarle uno al numero mayor una vez que se encontró) :

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TreintaNumerosIngresoMayor {
public static void main (String [] args){

    Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);

    int numero=0;
    int mayor=-9999;
    int siguiente=0;

    for(int i = 0 ; i<30 ; i++){
        System.out.println((i+1)+".Ingrese numero:");
        numero=teclado.nextInt();
        if(numero>mayor){
        mayor=numero;

        }
    }

    siguiente=mayor+1;

    System.out.println("El mayor es "+mayor+" y el que le sigue es "+siguiente);

}
```

}

Comment: Querrás decir el número mayor y el inmediatamente inferior entre todos los que has ingresado. Es así?

Answer (score 2):

Ya lo he probado y me ha funcionado bien.

Aquí tienes el código para que lo pruebes:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class TreintaNumerosIngresoMayor {
public static void main (String [] args){
Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);

        int numero=0;
        int mayor=-9999;
        int siguiente=0;

        for(int i = 0 ; i<30 ; i++){
            System.out.println((i+1)+".Ingrese numero:");
            numero=teclado.nextInt();

            if(numero>mayor){
            mayor=numero;
            }else if(mayor>siguiente && numero>siguiente) {
                siguiente = numero;
            }
        }

        System.out.println("El mayor es "+ mayor +" y el que le sigue es "+siguiente);
    }
}
```

Espero haya sido de ayuda!

Comment: No termino de entender tu codigo.. podrias explicar como funciona? en la siguiente cadena esto no funciona 1 5 3 6 2

Answer (score 1):

Me parece que en este caso podrìas usar el método:

> [Arrays.sort(int[] a)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort(int[])) : Ordena el arreglo especificado en orden
>   numérico ascendente.

Agrega los números introducidos a un array y aplica el método para ordenar de forma ascendente los números, para posteriormente obtener los 2 números mayores.

Este sería un ejemplo basado en tu código:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);

int numero=0;
int cantidadNumeros = 30;
int numeros[] = new int[cantidadNumeros];

for(int i = 0 ; i<cantidadNumeros ; i++){
    System.out.println((i+1)+".Ingrese numero:");
    numero=teclado.nextInt();

    numeros[i] = numero;

}

 //Orderna Array
 Arrays.sort(numeros);

 System.out.println("El mayor es "+numeros[cantidadNumeros-1]+" y el que le sigue es "+numeros[cantidadNumeros-1]+1);

}
```